# SQL Statement to Spring Data - PersistentEntity must not be null

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-data

I´m doing a Web-Application with a Spring Boot Backend and an AngularJS frontend.
Database is MySQL.
I try do get the Top 5 Items out of my database. I´m doing this through the
@Query Annotation. I tried my SQL Statement directly onto the DB and i get the expected values.
SQL Statement:

```
 select item 
    from work_item   
    group by item  
    order by count(*) desc   
    limit 3
```

@Query:

```
@Query(value="SELECT WORK_ITEM_ITEM FROM WORK_ITEM GROUP BY WORK_ITEM_ITEM ORDER BY COUNT( *) DESC LIMIT 5", nativeQuery = true)  
List< String > find5MostUsedItems();
```

When i try to access the related URL i´m getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PersistentEntity must not be null!
```

Would be glad if someone could push me into the right direction.
In case you need more information, plz ask. (My first question :) )

Edit: my Entity:

```
@Entity
public class WorkItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "workItem_ID")
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "workItem_date")
    private LocalDate date;
    @Column(name = "workItem_mitarbeiterNummer")
    private int mitarbeiterNummer;
    @Column(name = "workItem_startTime")
    private LocalTime startTime;
    @Column(name = "workItem_endTime")
    private LocalTime endTime;
    @Column(name = "workItem_workDuration")
    private int workDuration;
    @Column(name = "workItem_item")
    private String item;
    @Column(name = "workItem_itemDescription")
    private String itemDescription;
```

Greetings!

Comment: I think you want `work_item.item` instead of `work_item_item`.

Comment: @willOEM nope, it´s the name of the column in my DB. Added my Entity Class in first Post. But TY :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try `SELECT WORKITEM_ITEM` instead of `SELECT WORK_ITEM_ITEM`

Comment: nope, but ty. The Column ist called with underscore.